# Find range of $y^2+12y$ in $2x^2+3+y^2+12y$, known some conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Avoiding some mistakes, the real question is here :

[image]!

What i can find is

$a=-5, b=3, a+b=-2 , ab = -15$

$p+q=1.5, pq = s/2$

$2x^2+3+y^2+12y$ has $D>0 = 9-8s>0 = s<9/8 = y^2+12y<9/8 = 8y^2 + 96y - 9 < 0$

Comment: You have done a mistake. $a=-3$ and $b=5$.

Comment: Yes. But i still cannot proceed

Comment: The graph of $2x^2+3+y^2+12y$ is an ellipse below $y$- axis which is not having any solution.

Comment: $y$ here is not an $y$ axis. It can be written $2x^2+3+g^2+12g$

Comment: Actually the graph is below $x$-axis and not $y$. By mistake I wrote $y$.

Comment: I added the real question

Comment: "known: 2x^2 + 3 + y^2 + 12y" - what is known? That isn't a statement. It is a formula. What do you actually know about this formula? You say it has solutions, but it is a formula, not a statement. It doesn't claim anything, so there is nothing to solve.

Comment: We solve the question

Comment: You can see the real question which more accurate and understandable

Comment: Use $\gamma, \delta=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-8b}}{4}$ with $b\lt\frac 98$.

Comment: Yes, after i got b<9/8 how to connect it to the condition $\alpha < \gamma$ ?

Comment: $\alpha\lt\gamma$ is equivalent to $-5\lt\frac{-3-\sqrt{9-8b}}{4}$. Solve this for $b$.

Comment: Thanks @mathlove